# Which compiler is right?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, constexpr

The following code builds correctly in clang++

```
class Number
{
    int _value;

public:

    constexpr Number(int value): _value(value) {}

    constexpr bool operator==(const Number rhs) const { return _value == rhs._value; }

    constexpr bool isOne() const { return *this == Number::ONE; }

    static const Number ONE;
};

constexpr Number Number::ONE(1);

int main()
{      
    return 0;
}
```

but fails in gcc++. The returned error is the following:

```
Error(s):

266649471/source.cpp: In member function ‘constexpr bool Number::isOne() const’:
266649471/source.cpp:11:65: error: the value of ‘Number::ONE’ is not usable in a constant expression
     constexpr bool isOne() const { return *this == Number::ONE; }
                                                                 ^
266649471/source.cpp:13:25: note: ‘Number::ONE’ was not declared ‘constexpr’
     static const Number ONE;
                         ^~~
```

Who's right here? Any workaround to declare *Number::ONE* *constexpr* inside *Number*?